# Выделить память в динамическом массиве не потеряв прежние данные

Tags: c++, классы, динамические-массивы

Здравствуйте!

Есть класс `Employee` и динамический массив `members`. При запуске программа считывает с файла все объекты класса `Employee` и добавляет их в этот массив:

```
std::ifstream infodatr("Members.dat", std::ios::out);
while(infodatr.read((char *)&Y, sizeof(Employee)))
{
    AddM();
    members[lich] = Y;
    ++lich;
}
```

Динамический массив расширяется на ходу, но на этом я и словил ошибку. При выделении памяти под новый слот, я теряю всю информацию которая хранилась в массиве.

```
void AddM()
{
    try
    {
        members = new Employee;
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc xa)
    {
        std::cout << "Не удалось добавить в дим. масив " << std::endl;
        system("Pause");
    }
}
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: А `vector` использовать нельзя?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите расширить массив динамически в стиле `С`, то для этого вам нужно выполнить целый ряд действий:

1. Создать новый указатель
2. Выделить память под новый массив
3. Скопировать все элементы прежнего массива в новый массив
4. Очистить старый массив
5. Заменить указатель на старый массив, новым

Если же Вам доступны любые средства `C++`, то обратите внимание на контейнеры типа `std::vector`.

Comment: Лучше заменить `Vector` на 'std::vector` .

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавить элемент в массив нельзя. Есть разные пути решения этой проблемы.
1) Заказывать с запасом
2) Выделить память под новый массив, скопировать все в него, удалить старый массив
3) Хранить вместе с данными указатель на следующий и предыдущий элемент

С первым пунктом все понятно. Второй способ реализует класс `std::vector`. Третий способ реализует `std::list`.
Если у вас в задании явно не сказано отказаться от библиотечных классов, то не изобретайте собственный велосипед, а сделайте так:

```
#include <vector>
class Employee{
//...
};
int main(){
    //Создаем ветор
    std::vector<Employee*> employees; 

    //Вносим столько сорудников сколько нам нужно
    employees.push_back(new Employee);
    employees.push_back(new Employee);
    employees.push_back(new Employee);
    //...

    //А дальше можно пользоваться ветором как обычным массивом
    Employee *employee = employees[1];

    //Ну и, разумеется, не забудьте удалить все в конце
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < employees.size(); ++i){
        delete employees[i];
    }
}
```

Посмотреть полное описание вектора можете [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/?kw=vector)

Comment: Ну зачем же после рекомендации использовать `std::vector` прикручивать ручное управление памятью?!

Comment: @alexolut, вы намекаете на умные указатели или автоматические переменные?

Comment: И то, и другое. В разных комбинациях. Для образовательных целей ТС достаточно просто хранить значение.

Comment: @alexolut, может да, а может и нет. Вдруг он там собирается полиморфизм использовать. А умными указателями решил не пугать человека, хватит с него контейнеров на сегодня :)